# Virus in windows killed mouse also not working in Ubuntu

Tags: mouse

I received a virus in Windows 7 that killed my ability to use my mouse in any way. It also froze up my computer. Then I installed Ubuntu. The mouse worked when I was operating off of the Ubuntu disc but when it was downloaded and installed and the disc removed my mouse stopped working. It did begin to work for awhile last night but this morning I logged in and now it's not working again. I was able to right click on things for awhile but now I can neither right nor left click.

I really think the virus in Windows is having an effect on my mouse in Ubuntu. I'd like to get rid of the Windows virus but I have no ability to get into Windows to do it.

Help?

Comment: This can't be a Windows virus. I'd rather guess your mouse has a hardware defect.

Comment: If you reinstalled your system (and didn't reinfect it with an infected pendrive or by doing what you did the first time) I think it's more likely your mouse is broken or misconfigured.

Comment: My mouse (it's a laptop with a pad mouse) worked fine before I got the virus. (I obtained the virus by clicking on an infected link in a webpage.) It also worked fine when I was using Ubuntu off of the disc. But once I started using Ubuntu from its downloaded state on my computer, the mouse is again not working properly. I inserted a wireless mouse and that also does not work.

Comment: The most logical answer to this is a hardware problem. A virus in windows affecting a mouse in a newly installed Ubuntu. I seriously doubt that. 1st we don't yet have virusses. 2ndly this would be a 1st.

Comment: Maybe it should be investigated as a "first"so that when the second and five hundredth occurs, there will be an answer to the problem. My hardware operated just fine before I picked up the virus and before Ubuntu was installed. If it's a hardware issue, would that also affect the wireless mouse I inserted which also did not work (on this computer but works fine on others)?

Comment: It's possible the virus killed your USB controllers in some strange way, but it sounds more like a coincidence, and Ubuntu just hasn't installed correctly.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that your average run-of-the-mill virus will infect your USB controllers/firmware and render your mouse unusable. I think it's much more likely that your computer is just experiencing hardware failure of some sort, and your mouse not working is just sheer coincidence. We know of no such malware (yet) that can attack installed versions of OSes, but not live disks. Finally, it's not really the MO of a malware writer to disable the computer -- they'd typically want it for a botnet or somewhere to get valuable data. Disabling a USB controller prevents that.

Comment: I forgot to point out that "pad mouse" indicates that the question is probably about a [touchpad](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchpad), which are usually not connected via USB (as you can read e.g. on Peter  Hutterer's blog). Just to not drift off commenting solely about USB controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relating the unwanted behavior to a virus, let's avoid any bias from more experienced users and assume that you accidentally triggered a feature of the computer you didn't know about or replace the word virus with [PUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentially_unwanted_program). There is the possibility that you found some piece of PUP which modifies the firmware in your computer, but the former is more likely. You could upload logs from Ubuntu to the Internet for further investigation (which might lead into the wrong direction), but it would be better to bring the computer to someone who you trust and with enough knowledge about computers so that she or he can troubleshoot issues with computers and Linux themselves and observe the problem first hand. Uploading all kinds of data like photos, videos or an disk image of the entire hard drive is just an unnecessary risk of privacy for an issue that might be trivial if observed first hand or tricky but possible to investigate by looking at your web browsing history and all the programs and data on your computer.

I'm sorry for using the answering function while not actually providing an answer (and voting to close your question — which is contradictory and discouraged), the amount of text and reading time, but this is the best advice I can come up with while not observing the issue first hand.